# Игнорирование нулей на стандартном выводе

Tags: c

Если программа определила введенную строку числом, нужно вернуть эту строку так, чтобы все нули, которые стоят в начале строки, до чисел от 1 до 9, игнорировались.

Я ввожу: `01234 010203 12045 0000123 0`

Программа должна ответить:

```
number: 1234
number: 10203
number: 12045
number: 123
number: 0
```

Библиотеки только те, которые уже подключены.

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf, scanf
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi

char buf[101];  // Max length

int isNumber (const char *buf) {

    int i = 0;

    // Checking each symbol.
    while (buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        if ( buf[i] < '0' || buf[i] > '9' )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else i++;
    }

    // If all symbols are numbers - convert from string to decimal and return.

    unsigned char input = atoi(buf);
return 1;
}

int main (void) {

  while(scanf("%100s", buf) != EOF)  // Scanning string until end of string.
  {
    if (isNumber(buf))   // If found number - print.
    {
      printf ("number: %s",buf);
    }
    else // If not number - just word.
    {
      printf ("word: %s",buf);
    }
    printf("\n"); //new line after each word/number
  } //end of while
return 0;
}
```

Comment: И? Если у вас в буфере строковая запись числа, то printf("%d", atoi(buff)) должно дать ровно то что вы хотите.

Comment: работает, спасибо. Вспомнил, что atoi конвертирует строку в целые числа, в которые 0  не входит.

Comment: Не по этому будет работать, а потому что printf не вставляет лидирующие нули.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ваш способ помог, но всплыла следующая проблема - при вводе более 10 чисел, выводятся совсем другие числа. Например я ввел - 1234,  мне и показало что я ввел 1234, а если ввести 12345678901, то выведет следующее число - 360786013. Есть ли решение данной проблемы?

Comment: atoi возвращает тип INT, который не может хранить число больше 2^32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас в буфере строковая запись числа, то `printf("%d", atoi(buff))` должно дать ровно то что вы хотите.